# Отображение данных в NavigationDrawer из БД, а в submenu - из strings.xml

Tags: java, android, база-данных, listview, android-navigation-drawer

Подскажите как сделать `NavigationDrawer` с субменю наподобие этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для меня основная сложность состоит в том, что данные в `ListView` я подтягиваю с БД, а категории субменю (по типу "настройки","feedback" и тд тп) храню в `string-array` внутри `strings.xml` . 
В данный момент я успешно отображаю в `NavigationDrawer` данные с БД. Но добавить туда пункты со `string-array` я затрудняюсь. Как правильно решить эту задачу?

И как правильно кастомизировать `ListView` чтобы на выходе получить  drawer наподобие изображенного на рисунке ( отступ от предыдущей части списка,заголовок, отделить пункты субменю divider-ом от основных категорий).

Туториалы подсказывают примерные варианты создания drawer-а с субменю. Но у меня немного другой случай,поэтому я не могу воспользоваться рекомендациями с туториалов,где категории,например, хранятся  в `menu`.
Буду признателен за советы в решении данной задачи. Спасибо

Comment: картинка размером 100х200 пикселей все проясняет, действительно... Вам не кажется, что она слишком большая? Может стоило прикрепить 10х20?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам надо знать, как программно добавить пункты в меню, то это делается так:

```
navigationView.getMenu().add(0, 1000, 100, "gr0, id1000, or100");
```

Comment: я ListView использую.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую ListView. Решил данную сложность, добавив footer.
Т.е. я создал `footer.xml` , в нем задал нужные мне элементы : separator, необходимые мне item-ы списка( "настройки" , "выход" ) , далее в `MainActivity`  прописал код :

```
View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_footer, null, false);
        mDrawerList.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Далее инициализировал элементы `footer.xml` таким образом :

```
TextView mSettings = (TextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.settingsItem);
      .....
```

Задал им необходимые значения и повесил `OnClickListener`-ы. Таким образом данные в список Navigation Drawer-а я добавляю с БД, а footer заполняю статическими данными. Все оказалось просто

Comment: Можно и так. Просто надо понимать, что footer/header у ListView это что-то типа обёртки над адаптером основным, коя добавляет элементы с другим типом. Т.е. можно заменить их добавлением типов элементов  в адаптер и грузить, в зависимости от типа из БД или откуда-то ещё.